# what is the meaning of " our conscious understanding of it "?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.lingq.com/learn/en/preview/item/431401/

> The human brain is a complex machine that has a life of its own underneath **our conscious understanding** of it.

What is the meaning of " our conscious understanding of it " ?. What can be used instead of that phrase in the above context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slightly easier if you remove the word *conscious* from the sentence and rephrase a bit:

> The human brain is a complex machine that has a life of its own **beyond our understanding of it**.

In other words, there's more happening in the brain than we can explain with our current knowledge.

Adding **conscious** is just a way of emphasising the word *understanding* - the assumption being that we only understand things by experiencing them with our conscious (awake/self-aware) state.

So, **...our conscious understanding of it** could be rephrased as **...what we currently know about it**